# browser zoom out breaks page layout

Tags: javascript, html, css, layout

I am having trouble when i zoom out my page in browser.

this is a simple page, body has a width of 970px, and devided into 2 parts, left and right. Left one is 300px and float to left with margin-right 10px, right one is 660px, and float right. This is ok when i zoom in or zoom out.

but when i change left width to 298px, and add right width to 658px, add 1px border to both parts, though it is ok in normal size, but when i zoom out(ctrl+ mouse wheel down) to 90%, the right part drop down and breaks the layout. You can see here for detail:[jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/yuuuuc/zSw6r/)

```
<body>
    <style>
    </style>
    <div id='left'>left</div>
    <div id='right'>right</div>
</body>
```

Comment: Use percent units (or any relative unit) to ensure fidelity when scaling from browser. Try 30% and 70%.

Comment: Also, to have pixel units for borders without adjusting section widths, set `box-sizing: border-box` so that borders are drawn inside width of div instead of outside.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

HTML doesn't like to work with decimal pixel numbers and that's exactly what happens when you zoom - all the pixel sizes get internally divided or multiplied (though multiplication isn't really a problem).

Think about it, how should it represent 268.2 pixels? It gets rounded. So if you have many of those not-divisible elements, you're bound to lose some pixels and that causes the layout to break. Also, that's why some zoom percentages work better than the others.

Comment: but when i remove border, and set left width to 300px, right width to 660px, and margin-left of left side to 10px, the page layout won't break no matter how you zoom. Why does the page layout not break in this situation?

Comment: The browser probably keeps the border there all the time, and since it can't be smaller than 1px, it stays 1px. While all the other elements shrink, the sum of child element widths becomes bigger than the container element width (due to the border and undivisible number rounding) causing the right-hand element not to have enough room and moving it to the new row. See what happens when you "normalize" the numbers a bit: http://jsfiddle.net/zSw6r/2/

Answer (score 2):

To give your layout some flexibility, use percentage widths for your divs and float left and right as suggested in previous answers, but do not set a margin. Allow the margin to be the space left over. Using exact widths or percentage values that add up exactly 100% there is a risk the layout will break in one or more browser for reasons explained by Shomz.

```
#left{
    float:left;
    width:30%;
}

#right{
    float:right;
    width:65%;
```

The space between the two elements will be a the same as a 5% margin, and less likely to break.