# Looks fine when it's 100% zoom but when I zoom out everything went out of place

Tags: html, css

[Here](https://www.dropbox.com/s/0bpx7j3nmpfp7o5/zooms.png?dl=0) is the image of the zooms:

[image]

I have no idea what's the problem.

my **HTML** code is basically like this:

```
<div class="wrapper">
  <div class="trimester">
    <table>
    </table>
  </div>
  <div class="trimester">
    <table>
    </table>
  </div>
  <div class="trimester">
    <table>
    </table>
  </div>
</div>
```

then my **CSS** code:

```css
.wrapper {
  overflow: auto;
}
.trimester {
  width: 33%;
  display: inline-block;
  vertical-align: top;
}
.trimester table {
  font: 12px Open Sans, sans-serif;
  border-collapse: collapse;
  text-align: center;
  width: 100%;
}
.trimester td {
  padding: 2px;
  overflow: hidden;
}
```

Comment: where is your html code?

Comment: Try background + height for `.trimester` to see the real situation. I believe that tables after zoom are wider than wrappers. Without `table-layout:fixed;` you won't set width to tables strict. Try also this property.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you can use `display:table/[-cell]` to solve this particularly issue

```css
*, *:before, *:after {
  box-sizing: border-box;
}
.wrapper {
  display: table;
  table-layout: fixed;
  width: 100%;
}
.trimester {
  width: 33%;
  display: table-cell;
  vertical-align: top;
}
.trimester table {
  font: 12px Open Sans, sans-serif;
  border-collapse: collapse;
  text-align: center;
  width: 100%;
  /*demo styles*/
  height:500px
}
.trimester td {
  padding: 2px;
}
/*demo styles*/
.trimester:nth-child(odd) {
  background: red
}
.trimester:nth-child(even) {
  background: green
}
```

```html
<div class="wrapper">
  <div class="trimester">
    <table>
      <tr>
        <td>1st table</td>
      </tr>
    </table>
  </div>
  <div class="trimester">
    <table>
      <tr>
        <td>2nd table</td>
      </tr>
    </table>
  </div>
  <div class="trimester">
    <table>
      <tr>
        <td>3rd table</td>
      </tr>
    </table>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: thank you so much!! that `display: table-cell;` worked! :D

Answer (score 0):

When looking around other posts on Stack Overflow, the general consensus is to use floats and percentage widths to construct your layout in order to mitigate browser zoom issues ([See this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20183942/browser-zoom-out-breaks-page-layout)).

Think about your use-case too. Zooming-in is far more likely, since it helps to read text if you have visual impairments. ([UX discussion](https://ux.stackexchange.com/questions/51421/should-a-large-company-worry-about-browser-zoom)). Therefore, unless your use-case explicitly requires zoom-out to be supported, it may not be worth debugging.

Comment: thank you. that zoom issue post taught me something new~ :D and also the "zooming-in is far more likely" is a good point~ just that having this issue kind of bugs me so i wana fix it. :)